# How to handle errrors using Python

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm developing a Python script that will serve as an API (hence the 200/500 codes), and I was wondering on any best practices when it comes to handling errors, especially that in the code I'm sharing here.

At the `main` level I may get 3 cases:

- a value: if everything goes well
- `None`: if an error occurs at the level of `func2` is caught
- a json object: if an error occurs at the level of `func1` is caught

```
def func1(param11, param12, param13):
    logger.info(f"calculating result")            
    try: 
        if param11 < 0:
            raise Exception ("param must be a positive number")

        result = param11 * param12 / param13                  
        return result
        
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Exception calculating func 1: {str(e)}")
        #return None

def func2(param11, param12, param13, func21,...):
    ...
    result = func1(param11, param12, param13)
    if result == None:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'message': "issue calculating func1",
        }
    # more code here
    return result

def main() -> int:
    #...
    temp = func2(param11, param12, param13, func21,...)
    #...
    print(temp)
    return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'message': "everything went well",
        }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Either use an existing exception or create your own if an error happens that the user of the code cares about and throw one. Otherwise just return one kind of value or a related union of values if it's needed. This question is really pure opinion, look into Zen of Python (which frequently is broken by what people do anyways). It's ugly to return None or value, three things are worse, make it explicit with a union if you must. Really though, document the exception, use a union if it makes sense, move on.